# Updating AutoLayout Constraints When UIView Height Changes

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I currently have a UIView (we'll call this `viewB`) added to a parent UIScrollView, which we'll call `scrollView`.  This functions as expected, with `viewB` being added like so;

```
viewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
viewB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
viewB.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
viewB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

`viewB` is taller than `scrollView`, hence its ability to scroll vertically.

At some point in my app, the user may tap a button, which adds more content to `viewB`, hence changing `viewB`'s height.  On that button tap, `scrollView` does not seem to know to update any of its constraints, and `viewB` ends up changing positions and does not appear as expected.

What methods would I call (and on which views) to force AutoLayout to tell `scrollView` that `viewB` has changed sizes?  Or would it be more efficient to remove `viewB` from `scrollView` and then re-add with new constraints?

Comment: The scroll view will handle content size changes on its own so I wouldn't focus on that. IMO, the custom view should be responsible for its sizing. Are you adding additional subviews to the custom view or expanding existing subviews?

Comment: What constraints do you have on viewB before and after the update that defines its height?

Comment: `viewB` has a number of subviews, each with a defined height constant (the lowest of which is also pinned to the bottomAnchor of `viewB`).  All of this functions normally until I alter `viewB`, by adding a new subView to the bottom of its lowest subview, updating the bottomAnchor constraint, and call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` in its parent, at which point its position completely changes (it seems to be losing its topAnchor).

Answer (score 1):

Subviews inside a view that's inside a scrollview should be hooked properly from top to bottom at any time , so when you add a new subview to viewB you need to insert it properly inside that chain then call

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

if for e.x you add it at the bottom then you should remove most bottom subview's bottom constraint with viewB and hook it to the top of the new view and re-hook that new's subview's bottom to viewB's bottom plus giving height & width & x constraint finally refresh the layout again which is a tedious problem so you either go with it or with this Tip

> Tip : instead of managing constraints manually with UIScrollView you can use a UITableView or replace viewB with a UIStackView that has easily remove/add/insert functions

Comment: Would I call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` in my subview (`viewB`) or in my parent view `scrollview`?  I tried in the parent view (`scrollView`) after taking your suggestions (removing `viewB`'s lowest subview's bottom anchor, adding my new view, hooking up the relevant constraints), but no change in behavior.

Comment: i assume the scrollView is inside a vc so view is the vc's main view ( parent of scrollView ) , can you share what you have did